# Dropdown Option Structure

Tags: symfony

I need to create a tree structure for my category options list in form.
My form type code for options list:

```
->add('discipline', 'entity', array('label' => 'Parent Discipline',
    'empty_value'   => 'Parent Discipline...',
    'required'      => true,
    'empty_data'    => null,
    'class'         => 'RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionType',
    'query_builder' => function(ProductionTypeRFQRepository $er) {return  $er->createQueryBuilder('w')->where('w.parent IS NULL')->addOrderBy('w.name', 'ASC');},
    'attr'          => array('class'=>'form-control login-input')))
```

As you can see I have connected Repository which will get options list from database in tree structure, but I don't know how exactly to do that. Now my Repository looks like this:

```
    <?php

namespace RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProductionTypeRFQRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllParents()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT p FROM RFQIronilBundle:ProductionType p WHERE p.parent IS NULL ORDER BY p.name ASC')
            ->getResult();
    }

    public function findAll()
    {
        return $this->findBy(array(), array('name' => 'ASC'));
    }
}
```

This repository only gets parents, but not the children from database.

Please, give some information where to find a solution for this.

**EDIT:**

For request, this is my Entity for categories:

```
    <?php

namespace RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ProductionType
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="production_type")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionTypeRepository")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionTypeRFQRepository")
 */
class ProductionType
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RFQ", mappedBy="discipline")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductionType", mappedBy="parent")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
     **/
    protected $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductionType", inversedBy="children")
     **/
    protected $parent;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return ProductionType
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Add children
     *
     * @param \RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionType $children
     * @return ProductionType
     */
    public function addChild(\RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionType $children)
    {
        $this->children[] = $children;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove children
     *
     * @param \RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionType $children
     */
    public function removeChild(\RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionType $children)
    {
        $this->children->removeElement($children);
    }

    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param \RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionType $parent
     * @return ProductionType
     */
    public function setParent(\RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionType $parent = null)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return \RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionType
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

And Entity for my RFQ in which I need this Tree structure with categories (I have removed all items which doens't need for problem):

```
    <?php

namespace RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * RFQ
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="rfq")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RFQ
{
    //RFQ overall
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductionType",inversedBy="name")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $discipline;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set discipline
     *
     * @param \RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionType $discipline
     * @return RFQ
     */
    public function setDiscipline(\RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionType $discipline = null)
    {
        $this->discipline = $discipline;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get discipline
     *
     * @return \RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionType 
     */
    public function getDiscipline()
    {
        return $this->discipline;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some liters of coffee and energy drinks I managed how to resolve my problem. I will write something like a tutorial here to help everyone who got this problem too, because it was very hard to find a nice tutorial how to do it.

1. Add these bundles to your `composen.json` and run `composer update`.

   ```
   "yavin/symfony-form-tree": "dev-master",
   "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "dev-master",
   "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.*@dev"
   ```

   links to bundles: [symfony-form-tree](https://github.com/Yavin/symfony-form-tree); [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions); [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle)
2. After adding bundles you need to register StofDoctrineExtensionBundle in `AppKernel.php`

   `new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle()`
3. Now you need to add right Gedmo annotations to category entity (my category calls `ProductionType.php`)

   ```
   <?php

   namespace RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
   use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

   /**
    * @ORM\Entity
    * @ORM\Table(name="production_type")
    * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository")
    */
   class ProductionType
   {
       /**
        * @var integer
        *
        * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
       private $id;

       /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="string")
        * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RFQ", mappedBy="discipline")
        */
       protected $name;

       /**
        * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductionType", mappedBy="parent")
        * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
        **/
       protected $children;

       /**
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductionType", inversedBy="children")
        * @Gedmo\TreeParent
        **/
       protected $parent;

       /**
        * @var integer
        *
        * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        */
       private $treeLeft;

       /**
        * @var integer
        *
        * @Gedmo\TreeLevel
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        */
       private $treeLevel;
       /**
        * @var integer
        *
        * @Gedmo\TreeRight
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        */
       private $treeRight;
       /**
        * @var integer
        *
        * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
        */
       private $treeRoot;

       // Generated setters and getters
   ```
4. Add extensions to your mapping and activate extension you need (in my case Tree)

   ```
   stof_doctrine_extensions:
       orm:
           default:
               tree: true
   ```
5. Now you need work with `symfony-form-tree`. first add services to `Resources/config/services.xml`

   ```
   <service id="symfony.form.type.tree" class="Yavin\Symfony\Form\Type\TreeType">
      <argument type="service" id="property_accessor"/>
      <tag name="form.type" alias="y_tree"/>
   </service>

   <service id="symfony.form.type_guesser.tree" class="Yavin\Symfony\Form\Type\TreeTypeGuesser">
      <argument type="service" id="doctrine"/>
      <tag name="form.type_guesser"/>
   </service>
   ```
6. At last you need to create form builder for `symfony-form-tree` to create hierarchical dropdown options list:

   ```
   ->add('discipline', 'y_tree', array(
       'class' => 'RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\ProductionType', // tree class
       'levelPrefix' => '--',
       'orderFields' => array('treeRoot', 'treeLeft'),
       'prefixAttributeName' => 'data-level-prefix',
       'treeLevelField' => 'treeLevel',
   ))
   ```

That's all! I am not saying that this is the right way to make hierarchical dropdown options list and maybe I have made some mistakes, but this is working for me perfect.